# Can we insert textbox/button in Google Spreadsheet without using any Google Form like Excel insert objects?

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

As we can insert any form objects in excel, like sameway in a sheet of google spreadsheet Can we insert textbox/button date picker. Or We should go with Google Forms for that.

Please confirm anyone. It would be great.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This seems relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9160839/does-google-docs-have-content-controls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an apps script and put a trigger to call it whe the user opens the spreadsheet.
Here is an example of apps script

```
function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var form = app.createFormPanel();
  var flow = app.createFlowPanel();
  flow.add(app.createTextBox().setName("textBox"));
  flow.add(app.createListBox().setName("listBox").addItem("option 1").addItem("option 2"));
  flow.add(app.createSubmitButton("Submit"));
  form.add(flow);
  app.add(form);
 sheet.show(app);
};
```

The spreadsheet is shared [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AkkQD4hSd4KAdDk0aUM5VUVDQnJXdE5odzcxalNXdGc&usp=drive_web#gid=0).

Comment: Thanks for the code. It would be really useful even I am trying to embed the form objects in the spreadsheet itself.